# How to fix ServiceConstructionException from cxf.service.factory occuring due to version upgrade?

Tags: java, swagger, cxf

I have updated **cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs** and **cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger** jars from 3.2.6 to 3.2.7 in my pom.xml and I am facing the following exception when performed a get request to **https://localhost:8443/vnflcm/v1/swagger.json**

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Servlet.init() for servlet [rest] threw exception</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [rest] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:216)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createServerFromApplication(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:527)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:121)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractEndpointFactory.initializeAnnotationInterceptors(AbstractEndpointFactory.java:274)
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractEndpointFactory.initializeAnnotationInterceptors(AbstractEndpointFactory.java:240)
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractEndpointFactory.initializeAnnotationInterceptors(AbstractEndpointFactory.java:232)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.createEndpoint(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:241)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:162)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createServerFromApplication(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:527)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:121)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.6</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: check if that route is allowed on that endpoint. This `UnsupportedOperationException` looks like that endpoint is not there or doesn't have some permission like disk write/read

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where should I verify the permissions? Can you please clarify on which endpoint that I need to check on?

Comment: Also, can you please provide me with steps to configure the swagger.json endpoint?

Comment: Configuring swagger probably this could help https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger.

Comment: Permissions depends on the implementation. And it is more like when we try to access an GET endpoint with some other request type this error happens. OR when we have configured a route to not access the db write, then it throws this error saying that this cannot write. It should be mostly the first case

Comment: We are using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet for our application

Comment: Can you check if there is a security layer in your application. Because this error is pretty generic and mostly happens when the service bean is not initialized initially or is lazy loaded(in case of using spring). Invocation of that bean causes this exception `ServiceConstructionException`. It is very generic. If we can have a bit clear picture it would be easy to help.

Comment: Does the problem also occur with the latest 3.3.0 release? Can you provide the full stacktrace or a running sample to reproduce the error?